# Is there a variable describing that a PR is being run from a fork?

Tags: azure-devops

The code/PRs in question are coming from github. Currently I have our pipeline set up (via the "triggers" configuration on the pipeline) to run tests on forks of our repository, but to not make secrets available.

This means that for contributor PRs, our first two jobs in the pipeline run successfully, but then the following 3 (which require credentials) fail, giving endless errors about the variable not being set. I'd like to set a `condition:` for the job like `and(succeeded(), not(???))` where `???` is some variable indicating that this "is a fork".

I know I could change my jobs to include the secrets in the environment and then check for the environment variable being set and bail out early if not, but that seems silly - I figure this information must be available somehow. As it is it creates a lot of confusion for contributors, who see a bunch of tests fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_ISFORK` is available. Can use it like:

`and(succeeded(), ne(variables['SYSTEM.PULLREQUEST.ISFORK'], 'true'))`

Here is a one liner to get all the environment variables for future reference:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'gci env:* | sort-object name'
```